# How to stop call onCreateView when switch different tab(like tab1, tab2) in android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a question, a tab bar at the bottom of `MainActivity` (extends `FragmentActivity`), 
when I launch the app, the fragment1(in tab1) and fragment2(in tab2) will call `onCreateView`,
and some loading operation(like scan something) in each fragent, but I don't know how to
stop call `onCreateView` when I switch two tabs, I just want to keep the loading state even I switch one from another.

How do I implement it (just use this way, I don't want to use tabhost)?

Comment: You didnt explain WHY do you want to stop call onCreateView?

Answer (score 6):

`Fragment.onCreateView` is standard part of [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and you should not be trying to prevent it from being called.

From what i understand, your onCreateView method is probably doing some ugly work and that is why you dont want it to be called. If that is the case, you should move this code to another lifecycle method, that will not be called so often (for example [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), or [onActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29), if you also need your activity context).

[onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) should be only used to inflate your layout, and possibly make references to ui components that you will need to interact with.

Comment: I mean i want the effect like TabHost without fragment, the activity will call onCreate method only one time, and update ui at the same time

Comment: Doesn't mean he is doing something ugly... For example, if a fragment needs to make a request to get a list, you don't want to do this request every time you change between tabs.

Answer (score 5):

If you call `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` on your `ViewPager`, `onCreateView` would only be called at the start.

Comment: But I want, Fragment A oncreateView() calls , when we on Fragment A, and Fragment B oncreateView() calls , when we on Fragment B, It calls all oncreateView() simulataneously and never call them againd during swiping of tabs

Comment: i am also facing same problem as  " Er Kimmi Dhingra " said ,i am not able to call oncreateView() again during swiping of tabs.please help me

Answer (score 0):

begin your loading in onCreate or onAttach method，then it will not be restarted with onCreateView.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
this page have the fragment life cycle.

Comment: but I want to keep the network operation keep the original state(even after switch tab2 and come back), so it will not update UI (like asynchronous loading images in listview)

Comment: If I got your meaning, you want keep the loading state, and donot restart it along with switch tabs, is it? when swipe tabs the fragment is just invisibel, not destroy, so when come back, just invoke its onCreateView, not onCreate again. isn't it?

Comment: yes, I found fragmentPagerAdapter can implement this function